# Android WorkManager not starting the worker

Tags: android, androidx, android-workmanager, workmanagers

I want to download certain files from the server at the start of the app .So I tried using Work Manager which gets enqueued from my custom Application class.But the Worker class is not getting triggered and the **state is only ENQUEUED and not going to RUNNING**.Below is my code:

**Application class:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            //.setRequiresStorageNotLow(true)
            //.setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
            .build();

    OneTimeWorkRequest request = new OneTimeWorkRequest
            .Builder(MyWorker.class)
            //.setConstraints(constraints)
            //.setInitialDelay(1,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addTag("download")
            .build();

    WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(request.getId()).observeForever(new Observer<WorkInfo>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(WorkInfo workInfo) {
            if (workInfo == null) {
                Log.d("download", "workInfo == null");
            } else {
                Log.d("download", "workInfo != null: " + workInfo.getState().toString());//This is giving ENQUEUED once..thats it
            }
        }
    });
    WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).enqueue(request);
}
```

**MyWorker class**

```
public class MyWorker extends Worker {

public MyWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
    super(context, workerParams);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {
    //Some file to download 
}
}
```

**build.gradle:**

```
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.3.2"
```

**Things i have tried:**

I tried adding an interval and also remove constraints, but then also, MyWorker is not triggered.

I have seen many SOF posts as given below but it didn't help me:

[Worker manager: not start work in enqueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57698710/worker-manager-not-start-work-in-enqueue)

[Why workers in work manager still in ENQUEUED state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51148201/why-workers-in-work-manager-still-in-enqueued-state?rq=1)

[Android WorkManager doesn't trigger one of the two scheduled workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54456396/android-workmanager-doesnt-trigger-one-of-the-two-scheduled-workers)

Comment: Try to remove @NonNull annotation from ```MyWorker``` constructor. Builder operates with it by reflection, this may cause an issue.

Comment: Thanks @AntonProkopov, but it doesn't work

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? Or did you choose a different solution? Thx.

Comment: Is your MyWorker an inner class? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55515760/18202